# fsck_hfs: What does the number pair after 'Invalid sibling link' mean?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I have been through a lot of googeling on how to restore a broken TimeMachine backup `sparsebundle`.

The thing is that the volume seems to be mostly intact. I can open it with hfs_explorer on windows, and finder in macOS.

What I do also see is that there is a "in progress" backup in there, but the mac that uses that sparsebundle says the TimeMachine backup is broken and it needs to make a new one, deleting all history.

Repairing it using `fsck_hfs` dosen't seem to work, and I've googled all error messages.

The only thing I can't decode, find anything about is this message:

```
** Checking catalog file
Invalid sibling link
(4, 405803)
```

So can anyone tell me what those numbers there mean? Do they have something to do with inodes or something else?